# How do I substitute a variable in an equation for another equation & then evaluate that expression in R?

Tags: r, rlang

My problem is fairly simple, yet I haven't found a solution. I've got the equation y = 3 + x & x = x1 + x2; where x1 = 3 & x2 = 4. These equations come from text files. Unsurprisingly, I expect y to be equal to 10. I've tried the following & clearly does not work.

```
x1 <- 3
x2 <- 4
y_equation <- "3 + x"
x_equation <- "x1 + x2"
y <- parse(text = y_equation)
y <- substitute(y, list(x = parse(text = x_equation)))
eval(y)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to replace the 'x'  in 'y_equation' with the 'x_equation' and then do the `eval`

```
eval(parse(text = sub("x", x_equation, y_equation)))
#[1] 10
```